# How to set a time limit while calling the cplex routine cplexmilp from Matlab

Tags: matlab, cplex

I have been using cplex solver to solve mixed integer linear programming problems (MILPS) for the last few years. To be specific, I was using the cplex routine cplexmilp to solve my optimization problem, whereas my Matlab version was 2016b and 2018b. I was using the function cplexoptimset in Matlab to set a time limit for the cplex solver. But recently I have installed the latest version of Matlab i.e. Matlab 2020a, unfortunately the cplexoptimset can no more be used to set a time limit. Rather, I get an error message from Matlab when I try to use it. Please tell me some solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

could you try

```
opt = cplexoptimset('cplex'); 
opt.timelimit=20;
```

?

Comment: I am aware of these two commands, I also have used them on earlier versions of Matlab successfully to change the time limit. But unfortunately in Matlab 2020a the first command you wrote, gives an error message. I guess there have been changes in the new versions of Matlab.